# Why does the image grow like crazy when I set display to inline

Tags: jquery, css, html, inline

My code looks like this

CSS~

```
 div{
 display:inline; <!-- this is where I need the help -->
 }


a img{
margin: 5px;
box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px #000;
-moz-box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px #000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px #000;

}
.getbig{ 
top: 0px;
width:136px;
height:112px;
}
.bigimage{
width:100%;
height:100%;
left:15px;
top:15px;
}
```

Html~

```
<div class="getbig">

<a href="../pictures2/band1.jpg" target="_blank" ><img  src="../thumbnails/1.jpg" width="136" height="112" class="bigimage" alt="No Limit Texas" title="No Limit Texas"></a> 

<a href="../pictures2/band4.jpg" target="_blank"><img src="../thumbnails/4.jpg"  width="136" height="112" class="bigimage" alt="No Limit Texas" title="No Limit Texas"> </a>

<a href="../pictures2/band5.jpg" target="_blank"><img src="../thumbnails/5.jpg"  width="136" height="112" class="bigimage" alt="No Limit Texas" title="No Limit Texas"></a>

<a href="../pictures2/band7.jpg" target="_blank"><img src="../thumbnails/7.jpg"  width="136" height="112" class="bigimage" alt="No Limit Texas" title="No Limit Texas"> </a>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('.bigimage').mouseover(function(){

  $(this).stop().animate({
      "width": "105%",
      "height": "105%",
      "left":"0px",
      "top":"0px"
      }, 200,'swing');
}).mouseout(function(){ 
  $(this).stop().animate({"width": "100%","height":"100%","left":"15px","top":"15px"},200,'swing');
});;
 });
```

So all this does is just make an image grow a by 5% when I hover over it and then return to normal when I mouse off.

Here is my Question:  Why, when I choose display: inline, does all those images grow like crazy.  My problem is that when you display this in the brower, it's all under each other and I don't want that.  I want them each next to each other or like an in-line, but when I set that div to display:inline; it just makes everything grow MASSIVE.

Any ideas?

Comment: A fiddle set up with the problem would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you have set the width and height to grab 100% of the container div.
I have replicated your code and demonstrated in [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eqau7/3/)

```
var divheight = $('.bigimage').height();
var divwidth = $('.bigimage').width();
$('.bigimage').mouseover(function() {



    var new_height = divheight * 1.05;
    var new_width = divwidth * 1.05;
    $(this).stop().animate({
        "width": new_width + "px",
        "height": new_height + "px",
        "left": "0px",
        "top": "0px"
    }, 200, 'swing');
}).mouseout(function() {
    $(this).stop().animate({
        "width": divwidth,
        "height": divheight

    }, 200, 'swing');

});;​
```

Note that I have set my variables outside of the hover function, the reason is that my height() and width() functions grab the actual current size of the image.

Also, I have changed your css a little bit.

Least but not last you can use CSS3 transitions if you know the actual width of each image

```
.bigimage{
    left:15px;
    top:15px;
    width:112px;
    height:160px;
     -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transform:rotate(0deg);
    -webkit-transform:rotate(0deg);
    -o-transform:rotate(0deg);
    -ms-transform:rotate(0deg);

}



.bigimage:hover {
    height:120px; 
    width:200px;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transform:rotate(0deg);
    -webkit-transform:rotate(0deg);
    -o-transform:rotate(0deg);
    -ms-transform:rotate(0deg);
}
```

Comment: That's pretty neat. Thanks! Actually I'm not to good with jQuery, and I've been learning little by little.  Thanks for the help and I'll be looking at this code for the next hour probably.

Comment: I was happy to help, I think the problem is in your CSS, don't hesitate to ask for more help.